# laravel advance role permission with groups and modules

Tags: acl, user-permissions, laravel-9, laratrust

I have implmeneted [Laratrust](https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust) which works just fine. traditionally a role is assigned to a
user, a user can have one or many roles and a role can have many permissions.

I'm working on a project where requirments are little changed, a role can have multiple modules (airport, users, roles, permissions, bookings). each module can have a group (view, create, edit, delete, restore) and each group will have permissions. the purpose of grouping is that a single group can have all available permissions.

I have created a rough diagram to express what i want, the tables can be increased or decreased as long as the flow is achieved. Does anyone know if this flow is possible using any of the famous laravel permission packages such as [santigarcor/laratrust](https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust), [spatie/laravel-permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

for the reference i want to create something like this, https://github.com/eminiarts/nova-permissions#edit-view

Any help is highly appreciated, thankyou.

[image]